# BCM2835 - L2 cache coherency, how does it work?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, cpu-cache

With BCM2835 VideoCore, we have a L2 cache for the GPU that can also be used by the ARM core. The mode of operation for the cache is selected through the top two bits from the memory address (in the context of BCM2835, that's the bus address), using the following scheme:

```
0x0 L1 and L2 cache allocating and coherent
0x4 L1 non-allocating, but coherent. L2 allocating and coherent
0x8 L1 non-allocating, but coherent. L2 non-allocating, but coherent
0xc SDRAM alias. Cache is bypassed. Not L1 or L2 allocating or coherent
```

[image]

I have trouble understanding alias number 4 - the L2 cache coherent option. In this case, the L2 cache is coherent relative to what? The SDRAM? If that's the case, does it mean that each entry in the L2 cache will be invalidated when that memory location in SDRAM becomes a subject of a change?

If that's the case, let's look at alias number 8, where we use the L2 cache in an non-allocating but coherent manner. What does that mean? How can we have coherency between SDRAM and L2 cache if we are not allocating a L2 cache entry in the first place?

Comment: I think that the 'non-allocating' means [no write allocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies).  The table always has things 'coherent'.  0xc is just no cache which is of course coherent as the SDRAM is a single entity.  Coherent means the RAM and cache are the same.  If you buffer writes, they are not the same although you can use bus snoop (master 1 know what master 2 does and says have wait a sec, that is dirty) to make write buffered  cache coherent. See: [MESI at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol).

Comment: So, 0 = bus snoop L1/L2, 4 = bus snoop L2 only, 8 = no bus snoop.  The GPU will be dominate with writes. Vertexes are small versus the raster data.  However, it will typically re-write a whole SDRAM line (cache line too) so  these things are more important to the CPU work load.  Do you read/modify/write pixels?  Then snooping is needed.  Otherwise snooping may decrease performance slightly.

Comment: So if a peripheral writes to SDRAM using DMA, no matter the alias used, and we detect that this write will make some of the caches incoherent, we flush them?

Comment: Yes, you need to **invalidate** if the buffers are written with DMA no matter what.  It is only for CPU/GPU interaction that these parameters matter.  For an LCD controller reading via DMA you just need the GPU to write **flush** at the end (on a frame interrupt) so that screen is current.  Flush writes your data out.  Invalidate says your data is not right and re-read.  You might need to do either for the CPU and/or GPU depending on what is going on.  Usually both caches (L1/L2).  For DMA snooping does nothing.  DMA buffers are usually uncached/un-buffered with no need to flush/invalidate.

Comment: Ok, i think it's more clear now, thank you. One last question - in the case of BCM2835, what unit is taking care of providing coherence through bus snooping of the GPU <-> CPU transactions? The Snoop Control Unit in the ARM core?

Comment: The SCU is taking care of L1 to L2 coherency which is shared. Coherency usually only matters for thing that 'crunch numbers' or do R/M/W operations.  I think there is an optional 'ACP' which is for L2/DDR(or other AXI slave) coherency.